# Jquery for each returning deleted items

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Im having some troubles with this behavior of the $.each in Jquery.

I have an array that holds all the info of the entities to be saved later.

Meanwhile the user is doing his stuff, he can add and delete items. 
So, in the array (with a JSON syntaxis), I get "leaps" in the elements like this:

Array = {0:"foo", 2:"bar",3:"foo2"}

When Im going to save all this info, I do a $.each in the array expecting that the function will return all the elements in the array but intead it returns the 0-element, 1-element, 2-element, etc. Following the example, it returns an undefined element!

Is this an expected result? Or a "known" issue? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

pd: english is not my tongue lenguage.

Comment: show your `$.each` loop code

Comment: Maybe the main thing to realize is that `{0:"foo", 2:"bar",3:"foo2"}` is an js plain Object, not an Array. If elements are removed from a non-sparse Array with `.splice()`, then the indices, 0, 1, 2 etc, remain sequential (no "jumps"). A plain Object with "integer" keys will not behave the same way. Its keys don't imply order even though they are (or at least appear to be) integers.